# What controls Visual Studio .net core version?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I can't figure out for the life of me why all my projects always have the NETStandard.Library 1.6.1 installed.

If I run `dotnet --version` from the command line I get the following output

```
2.1.0-preview1-007102
```

My .csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Visual studio blocks me from upgrading via nuget within visual studio, so I always have to either manually install `NETStandard.Library 2.0.0` or search stack overflow and add in that implicit version tag to the .csproj, but WHY do I have to do this?  What is telling visual studio that the default should be 1.6?

What I mean by blocking me from installing NETStandard.Library 2.0.0 below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This NuGet package is not supposed to be manually edited, though in your case it looks like an old version of the tooling is used that isn't supposed to be used with `netstandard2.0`.

Check if you have the latest VS version (currently 15.4.0) and no `global.json` in the project directory hierarchy that sets the SDK version to something lower than `2.0.0`.

Also, I suggest not using daily builds (e.g. your 2.1.0 preview) for production work as you need to constantly update it to be on the safe side, or create a `global.json` document in your project directory containing:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

To make sure you are using a "good" version (2.0.2 is the version shipped with VS 2017 15.4.0). You will need to close and re-open the solution again after doing this.

Comment: I have the latest VS, and even downloaded enterprise trial just to try out a new one.  Same thing.  The odd part is that the cli ``dotnet build`` works exactly as expected.  Also my build server builds these with no problems.  I don't know if Visual Studio is using a different ``dotnet`` executable or what is going on.

Comment: VS carries an "SDK resolver" that locates the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` folder from a .net core sdk version. It looks for a global.json to control it but should resolve to a 1.1.0 or 2.* version. you can check with `dotnet --info` where the 2.1.0 preview is and try to delete it. (`where dotnet` is a good indication as well)

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the 2.0 preview sdks, along with the 1.0 preview sdks i had installed and everything started working as I would expect them to.  I'm not sure why the presence of the preview SDKs caused this but oh well, glad to have it fixed!